# Hadoop job is submitted but it still not finished after few hours

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I built an distributed environment with a virtual box. It contains 3 nodes, 1 master node and 2 slave nodes.

I've already put some data on HDFS, and I executed the following command:

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount input/ output/
```

Here is the log I got after few hours:

```
15/05/03 20:48:30 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop01/192.168.10.11:8032
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/05/03 20:48:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/05/03 20:48:32 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1430656198359_0002
15/05/03 20:48:32 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1430656198359_0002 to ResourceManager at hadoop01/192.168.10.11:8032
15/05/03 20:48:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop01:8088/proxy/application_1430656198359_0002/
15/05/03 20:48:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1430656198359_0002
```

Comment: First check `http://hadoop01:8088/proxy/application_1430656198359_0002/` link in your browser...I think your job was held up in ACCEPTED state...pls confirm..

Comment: I've just checked that. The state of the application is 'ACCEPTED'. What else should I check? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Be careful, @hserus is talking about the state of the job and you reply about the state of the 'application'. You should also check the log of that job, not only its state.

Comment: @chomp is this is the full log of the job? I've found that there is an unhealthy node.
http://i.imgur.com/Zo13cOP.png

Comment: No @ramskull, that is the resource manager, from there you can easily access to the logs of your job or applicattion (just see that some places are links, and you can follow them for analyze the real logs), but you must do some stuff first.  
Install [map-reduce job history server](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap4-4.html), and test wordcount again. If anything goes wrong, clicking in the link of Tracking UI you can access, finally, to the job's log and tell us what is really happening there.

Comment: @chomp, I've already start the history server and executed the wordcount again. But the Tracking UI still unassigned. I checked the job history server with `jps` and the job history server is on. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @ramskull maybe you should create a separate question for that problem, the Tracking UI it's a very useful tool and if you don't see the link there, you probably had some configuration problem around it.

Comment: @chomp ok I got it. I will deal with this problem first.